# Excel VBA add row at the end of each value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to automate a spreadsheet that updates the data we've received from clients in our DB.
First step is to add blank rows at the end of each column so I can populate them with new data.

[image]

Logically I think it'd be something like:
1. Find last instance of "CLIENT 1" 
2. Add rows

Any advice is appreciated. Please let me know if this is not descriptive enough.

Comment: Why do you need to add rows, rather than put values in the next available row? Do you mean you need to copy rows? in any event check out the .End property of the Range object: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839539.aspx

Comment: 1. I need to add rows so I can populate them with the latest data received.
2. This is only my second project with VBA. I have no idea what I'm doing. I'm not trying to take advantage of good SO people. I tried a couple things but nothing I can find is even close. I figured out a really long work around. But I figured there must be some easy For loop or even a single function out there that I dont know about.

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to add a blank row, since you can add it to the bottom and then sort the rows by Client and then by date, giving you the end result you are looking for. Check [here](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba) for identifying the last row, and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx) for sorting the table. If you have trouble implementing these functions, add an edit to your question including the code you have so far and we will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You could you run a simple loop to compare the values in each cell of the column and add rows when the value changes:

```
Sub InsertClient()

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
        If i = lastrow Then
        Range("A" & i + 1).Value = Range("A" & i).Value
        End If

        If Range("A" & i).Value <> Range("A" & i - 1).Value Then
        Rows(i).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
        Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & i - 1).Value
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```